# Is "WAV parameter set" the right name?

Tags: audio, naming, wav, audio-streaming, pcm

I'm sending some metadata to an external component whose job is to play PCM WAV files streamed over the network. The metadata consists of the following fields:

- Samples per sec
- Bits per sample
- Channels
- Extra info size

How would you call this metadata? Is "WAV parameter set" a good name?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API uses the term "Wave Format". I tend to think of it in that term at least (as it describes the format of the WAV file.